# using tikz to draw a flattened polyhedron

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to create the net of a flattened hexagonal based box. Each side of the box is a slight trapezium (so in 3D the sides will not be perpendicular to the base, but that's not important to the question). Since each side is the same but only positioned differently I tried the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\side}[1][10]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (sO) at (0,0);
\path (sO)--++(-90:2) coordinate (sB);
\path (sO)--++({#1}:1) coordinate (sC);
\path (sB)--++({-1*#1}:1) coordinate (sD);
\draw (sO)--(sB)--(sD)--(sC)--(sO);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path (O)--++(0:2)  coordinate (A1);
\path (O)--++(60:2) coordinate (A2);
\path (O)--++(120:2) coordinate (A3);
\path (O)--++(180:2) coordinate (A4);
\path (O)--++(240:2) coordinate (A5);
\path (O)--++(300:2) coordinate (A6);

\draw (A1)
--node[sloped,rotate=90,anchor=west]{\side}(A2)
--node[sloped,rotate=90,anchor=west]{\side}(A3)
--node[sloped,rotate=90,anchor=west]{\side}(A4)
--node[sloped,rotate=-90,anchor=west]{\side}(A5)
--node[sloped,rotate=-90,anchor=west]{\side}(A6)
--node[sloped,rotate=-90,anchor=west]{\side}(A1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The sides are not flush on the sides of the hexagon. Is there a way to do this elegantly?

Or perhaps my code could be improved, in particular to have the same node information (sometimes I needed `rotate=90`, other times `rotate=-90`).

[image]

Comment: If someone could include a picture, I'd be grateful.

Comment: This TeXample by Till Tantau should be of interest: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/foldable-dodecahedron-with-calendar/

Comment: Try to add `inner sep=0pt` in `node[sloped,...` Is this what you want?

Comment: The folding library only seems to have one predetermined shape. It would be nice to see how the repeated shapes are easily positioned. The `inner sep` though solved that space problem.

Comment: @Ignasi Your comment of the `inner sep=0pt` solves the problem of the spaces. If you state this as an answer I will accept. Concerning the elegance of the code, repeating blocks and repositioning them, I posted a follow on question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix `inner sep=0pt` (or even better -\pgflinewidth) for your `\side` nodes. 
Next code shows both options. You can also see why your trapezium are not join to hexagon. Every node has a (by default not zero) `inner sep` between its contents and node border.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\side}[1][10]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (sO) at (0,0);
\path (sO)--++(-90:2) coordinate (sB);
\path (sO)--++({#1}:1) coordinate (sC);
\path (sB)--++({-1*#1}:1) coordinate (sD);
\draw (sO)--(sB)--(sD)--(sC)--(sO);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\path (O)--++(0:2)  coordinate (A1);
\path (O)--++(60:2) coordinate (A2);
\path (O)--++(120:2) coordinate (A3);
\path (O)--++(180:2) coordinate (A4);
\path (O)--++(240:2) coordinate (A5);
\path (O)--++(300:2) coordinate (A6);

\draw (A1)
--node[sloped,rotate=90,anchor=west, inner sep=-\pgflinewidth]{\side}(A2)
--node[sloped,rotate=90,anchor=west, inner sep=-\pgflinewidth]{\side}(A3)
--node[sloped,rotate=90,anchor=west, inner sep=0pt]{\side}(A4)
--node[sloped,rotate=-90,anchor=west, inner sep=-\pgflinewidth]{\side}(A5)
--node[sloped,rotate=-90,anchor=west, inner sep=0pt]{\side}(A6)
--node[sloped,rotate=-90,anchor=west, draw=red]{\side}(A1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]